# How to disable selective qt services

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to disable the Qt Network Services and related functionality.
In the Qt configuration, there is an option `-skip` to skip the high-level source directory from the build.
But I want to disable the network service.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `"Qt Network Services and related functionality"`?

Comment: @G.M. When I run my application in the logs I see the network service is crashing, as I am not using anything from the network service so I thought I should disable it. I am getting the below error in the logs `ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(286) Network service crashed, restarting service.`.  and I am not sure of the error. I am using Qt 5.15.3 version.

Comment: That looks like a [chromium](https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=17757) issue rather than anything `Qt` specific.

Comment: @G.M. As per the post it worked after removing flag "--browser-subprocess-path" but I am not able to find this and from where I need to remove it? or this error can be ignored?

Comment: This flag is in "qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/content/public/common/content_switches.cc" file. Do I need to disable this from this file and rebuild qt or what? Is there a way to disable it runtime?